# P/Invoke of an enum

Tags: alignment, pinvoke, packing

I wanted to call the DISM API from C# to find out which optional Windows features are installed. DISM functions don't appear on the well-known pinvoke.net site, so I started figuring it out with the P/Invoke Interop Assistant tool.

The problem involves a structure that starts like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DismFeatureInfo
{
    /// PCWSTR->WCHAR*
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string FeatureName;

    /// DismPackageFeatureState
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public DismPackageFeatureState FeatureState;

    /// PCWSTR->WCHAR*
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string DisplayName;
```

I have a pointer to an unmanaged `DismFeatureInfo`. When I use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` I get a `FatalExecutionEngineError` exception.

If I comment out all the fields from `DisplayName` onward (only keeping the first two) then it works and I get a valid string in `FeatureName`.

If I use the debugger Memory window to inspect the memory at the address of the structure, it is laid out as expected. I'm running in 64-bit, and it starts:

```
[ 8 bytes ] // pointer to a string containing the feature name
[ 4 bytes ] // enum value 
[ 8 bytes ] // pointer to a string containing the display name
```

What's more, if I manually do the offsets to read the pointers and then get the strings from them:

```
var featureName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(featureInfoPtr));
var displayName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(featureInfoPtr, 8 + 4));
```

That works fine - `displayName` contains the display name.

Which all suggests that the `enum DismPackageFeatureState` is being marshalled as the wrong size. From inspecting the raw memory it is definitely supposed to be 4 bytes. And I've put an attribute saying it should be `I4`.

And if I change the `FeatureState` field to say:

```
public UInt32 FeatureState;
```

then I still get the exception. So what is going on?

*(NB. I'm specifically interested in the P/Invoke aspects, not my original problem. I've since found the information I needed much more easily via `new ManagementClass("Win32_OptionalFeature")` but am still puzzled by what I found while trying to get P/Invoke working and would like to know what was going on.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a mismatch of alignment rather than size. The `DisplayName` pointer has 8 byte alignment. But according to your analysis of the layout, it is placed on a 4 byte boundary. The C# code in your question will give `DisplayName` an offset of 16. But your analysis says that it has an offset of 12. This leads me to suspect that the native `struct` is in fact packed.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct DismFeatureInfo
....
```

should resolve your problems.

**Update**

I can confirm that my hunch was correct. The following can be found in dismapi.h wrapping the struct declarations:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
```

Comment: Where did you find that header?

Comment: Perfect, for some reason I'd assumed that `LayoutKind.Sequential` implied packed.

Comment: In fact packed is unusual. The almost universal standard is aligned. This API is non-standard.